# Windows defender detecta una app mía desde Pyinstaller como virus

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, exe

Estuve haciendo una app en Python y la compile como .exe con ayuda de PyInstaller, pero cuando comparto este .exe a otros dispositivos Windows (Trojan:Win32/Sabsik.FL.A!ml). ¿Qué puedo hacer?
El repositorio: https://github.com/xThoms/Downloader-from-YT

Comment: probar con otro generador de exe, como cx_freeze

Comment: No sos el primero, ni serás el ultimo. Lamentablemente, no hay mucho más que se pueda hacer que reportar el falso positivo al proovedor del antivirus o, quizás, probar otro compilador. Pero no se si otros tienen el mismo problema o no...

Comment: _Decirle a los usuarios del exe que añadan la excepción_ suena a una opción. No sé si en pyinstaller puedes firmar el exe de alguna forma o algo así.

Comment: Por las dudas, proba deshabilitar la compresión UPX, eso suele bajar las chances de detección de los AVs.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es distribuir el exe diciéndole a los usuarios que añadan la excepción en defender si es una cosa interna menor.

Si es para usuarios externos y hace más ruido, [por acá](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45316660/236345) dicen que el camino es firmar tu exe con un certificado válido de una CA pública. Dan un enlace de ejemplo a lo que DigiCert [entrega](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing) como guía para firmar código. Windows reconoce DigiCert como CA público de confianza y no repudia tu ejecutable. Obvio cuesta dinero.

Usar un certificado autofirmado implica incluir la clave pública que cada usuario debe instalar en su terminal para que Windows no repudie el ejecutable.